# In magento the categories are not displayed in front end?

Tags: magento, categories

In magento categories, one of the sub categories is not displayed in frontend. But while adding the product in backend it get the updation in that product is successful. Can anyone give the exact answer for my problem.
Thanks in advance

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Answer (score 0):

you may be set `IS Active : NO` for that sub category, change settings to "YES", it will display in frontend.

Comment: please follow the sub category that is displaying, check you are using same settings for both by comparing each field.

Comment: Actually i update 6 categories in all categories menu. bt only one category is not displaying. rest of them are showing.

Comment: is there any backend configuration for menu ? did you checked that ?

Comment: How to check that?

Comment: did you added those 6 menus or before only it was there ?

Comment: also you can see category url try to open sitelink/category-url.html in browser tab and tell

whether category is opening or not ?

Comment: i updates those menus in manually. bt only one category is not displaying

Comment: did you tried to open `sitelink/category-url.html`in browser tab

Comment: means you are telling there is separate configuration for menu, the categories are not displaying under menu in site ?

Comment: if possible please post a screenshot here of the category you created in backend. or try one more sub category and check

Comment: Totally i added 6 categories. but in the place of 5th category name is not displayed. whatever i add in that place its not showing. if i add after 5th categories it will be showing.

Comment: than leave about 5th one and continue from 6th one. for my knowledge there is some mis configuration in 5th one.

Comment: Then how can i add the 5th category name. IF i add next to 6th, it will replace as 6th, and 6th will replace as 5th. so the same prob will occur

Comment: can you please post screenshots

Comment: how to post screenshots? can u pls tel.

Comment: type "prntscrn" buttton in keyboard, than go for paint and "ctrl +V" , than save it and upload here : http://prnt.sc/
than send me link.

Comment: i took snapshot, am asking about how to upload it here. where to find the upload option

Comment: in my categories the premium arrangements are displaying. rest of them are shown

Comment: its better if you delete that category and create again

Comment: @SaranyaR Did you found solution, if so please accept the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Please compare category settings from other category that show in frontend.

If you use any custom theme then please check the theme settings for category

Comment: Can u pls explain it briefly?. bcoz i'm new to magento.. Actually i update 6 categories in all categories menu. bt only one category is not displaying. rest of them are showing.

Comment: Please check this "Include in Navigation Menu" setting should be yes

Comment: Please reindex it by go to System >>  Index Management

Comment: Again it is not coming.